# Port is closed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, port-forwarding, qbittorrent

I am using `http://www.canyouseeme.org` and `http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/` to find out whether my port is opened for connection or not.

I am not able to seed the torrents. It keeps telling me that seeding port is closed from external IP. Not only seeding port but all the ports are closed for incoming connections.

I am using `qbittorrent`.

What I have tried:

- In my router N6400 I have enabled port forwarding and UPnP.
- Without firewall, I tried `iptables` command for specific port but didn't worked.
- With firewall, I added inbound rules for port but it didn't work.

I have tried by directly connecting my laptop to Modem via LAN but still port was closed so router does not have any problems with port forwarding.

Here is the output of `ntlp | grep 8999`

```
tcp  0   0 172.21.20.219:8999      0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      4459/qbittorrent
udp  0   0 172.21.20.219:8999      0.0.0.0:*                  4459/qbittorrent
```

Comment: Several problems could be happening simultaneously. Just because the problem still shows up when you remove the router doesn't mean there's not also a problem with the router. In fact, a lot of ISPs won't allow a new MAC address to work with the modem, so it's possible you've added another problem.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex What can be done in this situation ?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Open external ports for qBitTorrent?  Try turning Port Forwarding off in the router first.  If that doesn't work, try `sudo ufw disable`.

Comment: @Fabby  I am not able to seed the torrents. It keep telling me that seeding port is closed from external IP. Firewall is already turned off.

Comment: What IPv4 address are you using for testing?  Does your ISP provide you with full IPv4 connectivity on a public address, rather than something like Carrier-Grade NAT ?

Comment: @user4556274 I have talked to ISP provider and they provide full connectivity on public address. Anyway I am using VPN so that want be a problem.

Comment: @JBaba, Could you [edit] the question and add the output of `tracepath -b -m5 askubuntu.com` & `curl ifconfig.me/ip`

Comment: @user.dz I have added requested info.

Comment: @JBaba, your router have public IP, ok. Could you post a screen shot of your qbittorrent settings (connection tab) and port forwarding entry in the router. I think same reason as hobbs's answer.

Comment: @user.dz requested images has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There three interfaces up:

```
lo   127.0.0.1    ##local loopback
tun0 172.21.20.45 ##VPN tunnel
wlo1 192.168.1.2  ##LAN Interface
```

So the port forwarding is correct with `192.168.1.2` local IP from the router.

The issue seems with qbittorrent that seems configured to use only `tun0` interface.

1. From qbittorrent menu: Tools → Options... → Advanced → Networ Interface: Select `Any Interface`
2. Restart qbittorrent

Check `netstat -ntlp | grep 8999`, you should find: `0.0.0.0:8999`

[image: qbittorrent interface bind settings]

Comment: I have tried that but as this ip is not registered under router. So if try to choose port forwarding on `172.21.20.219` this it gives me invalid ip address error.

Comment: `192.168.1.2` this static ip assigned by router.  And `172.21.20.219` is interface ip assigned by Qbt. please tell me how to do correct setup ?

Comment: @JBaba, Could you post the output of  `ifconfig -a` and `route` commands  plus the DHCP page from router. It seems you have dual subnet setup (possible wrong)

Comment: please see the requested output

Comment: `172.21.20.45` this is my current interface ip for Qbt

Comment: @JBaba, updated my answer. could you recheck.

Comment: ok I got this `0.0.0.0:8999` but still incoming connections timed out.

Comment: @JBaba You have to use web-browser  without VPN, because those port scanning websites will try to scan your VPN provider IP. You port should be ok if you want to confim, disable the tunnel temporary then test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50652/discussion-between-user-dz-and-jbaba).

Comment: Tired without VPN still same incoming connection not working. I am also checking my connectable on tracker where my VPN is registered.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, the local address on those sockets is `172.21.20.219`, which is a private IP address, and presumably not the one that your traffic is actually coming to. If the sockets were listening on any port, they would display `0.0.0.0:8999` or `:::8999`. The problem lies with qbittorrent, that it's binding to that address specifically.

Comment: how do you change this binding from QBittorrent ?

Comment: @JBaba I've never used it. Look in the settings for anything like "bind address" or "bind interface".

Comment: I changed this configuration now it show my local ip. But still it says port is closed.

Comment: @hobbs even 80 port is closed for incoming connections. I have changed settings which is what you suggested.